# Event before pressing a key or barcode scanner

Tags: c#, winforms, events

How would I do this? For example:

1. I have `textBox1` and input "SomeInput" then leave the `textBox1`. (Input using keyboard or barcode scanner)
2. When I return to `textBox1` the "SomeInput" is highlighted with `textBox1.SelectAll()`.
3. When I press a key the "SomeInput" is changed with the key I press. (Or use barcode scanner)

Now, how would would I insert "SomeInput"(the input before the key press) in the `textBox3`?

I tried the `textchanged` event but it insert the new key that is pressed.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
```

`Focus` event is not allowed.

[image]

Another Question: Does textChanged occur when a barcode is scanned?

Comment: Including the code that you've tried would make this question much more clear.

Comment: Are you looking for `keyDown` or `keyUp` or `KeyPress` events?

Comment: do not use the SelectAll Method, if you are wanting to append text it will default to the insertion point

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel - what is the most applicable with Barcode Scanner?

Comment: @Mark - I don't want to append text :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you `select all text in textBox1` as soon as its focus gets over,writing this code in the `textBox1.Enter` might help you achieve your need;

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (textBox1.SelectedText.Length == textBox1.TextLength)
 {
  textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text;
  textBox1.Text = "";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just try with keyPress Event

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
   textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text; 
 }
```

Comment: `textBox3.Text=textBox1.text ?`.It doesn't do what the OP is asking for,it only synchronizes textBox3 to textBox1,which means textBox3's text will be same as that of textBox1's all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyPress` event **is fired before the `Text` is changed**, so you can use it for your purpose:

```
//KeyPress event handler for your textBox1
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
   if (textBox1.SelectionLength == textBox1.TextLength && textBox1.TextLength > 0){
            textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text;
   }
}
```